# PHP str_replace in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, str-replace

The while function in str_replace only returns the first line of information. This is email template.

```
// I have a macro in my message. (member name)
$message = "Hi {%write_member_name%} how are you?";

$connect = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($connect)){


$membername = $row["member_name"];

$message = str_replace('{%write_member_name%}', $membername ,$message);

echo $message."<br/>";

}
```

The result I should have.

Hi **Jack** how are you?

Hi **Mike** how are you?

Hi **Alex** how are you?

But I get the wrong result:

Hi **Jack** how are you?

Hi **Jack** how are you?

Hi **Jack** how are you?

---

If I do not use the str_replace function it works correctly.

**How do I use the str_replace function in while loop?
Thank you.**

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated. Use mysqli or even better, PDO.

Comment: It will take a lot of time to fix all the software. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @MertA. Have you tried to print the `$row["member_name"]`? Is it also printing the same value all the time?

Comment: @Difster If I do not use the str_replace function it works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $connect = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members"); 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($connect)){
        $message = "Hi {%write_member_name%} how are you?";
        $membername = $row["member_name"];

        $message = str_replace('{%write_member_name%}', $membername ,$message);

        echo $message."<br/>";

    }
```

Comment: Sorry this is not the problem. There was a mistake when you were rewriting the codes here.

Comment: @Mert A. check it now

Comment: use @Stefan Avramovic solution

Comment: @Mert A. check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You use [**sprintf()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for this

> Replace the percent (%) sign by a variable passed as an argument:

```
$membername = "";
$connect = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($connect)) {
    $membername = $row["member_name"];
    $message = sprintf("Hi %s how are you?", $membername); // pass argument here
    echo $message . "<br/>";
    $membername = "";
}
```

> mysql_* functions officially deprecated and removed in PHP 7.0.0. You
>   should update your code with PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier:

```
$connect = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members"); 
while($icerik=mysql_fetch_array($connect)){

echo $message =  "Hi" . $row["member_name"] . "how are you? <br/>";


}
```